# boto ec2 get_all_instances hanging in VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I have a script which hangs when it tries to get the instances. I am running from a machine in a VPC and it worked a couple of weeks ago but does not. I'm assuming someone may have changed the Security Group or ACL settings however I cant see anything obvious. What rule woudl I be looking for which might block this and stop it from working. It runs fine on a machine outside of the VPC

```
reg = RegionInfo(name='eu-west-1', endpoint='ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')
conn = EC2Connection(aws_access_key_id=awsAccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=awsSecret, region=reg)
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
```

Thanks

Comment: We've discovered that when we associate our instance with an EIP the script works. This seems necessary though, as all I am trying to do is return a list of instance ids